# Maven plugin to handle licenses?

Tags: maven, licensing

As the Maven pom can contain license information, Is there some way that you could for example tell your build that "Apache v2" Licennses are ok, but GPL for example not and when you build Maven would return errors if needed dependencies have forbidden licenses and eventually ask you to accept unknown ones?

I know that there are plugins available that create a report of all used licenses in a project, but I couldn't find a single one that actually allow you to define what's ok, what's not and to ask for confirmation if it doesn't know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Comment: On the contrary ... I am talking about development in which I want to prevent usage of forbidden license types in my build. I know that licenses are a legal thing, but controlling my dependencies is a build thing. I see it similarly to constraints like "only dependencies which are valid osgi bundles" or similar constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In think I have found the tool I was looking for:
http://www.sonatype.com/clm/overview
But the solution consists of more than just a maven plugin, but it provides the services I was looking for and even more.

Answer (score 5):

Mojohaus (ex-Codehaus) have pretty flexible and mature [license plugin](http://mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) that should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for information on how to configure maven-license-plugin? Check [this link](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/wiki/Configuration)

Following is an example of usage:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                <header>${basedir}/src/etc/header.txt</header>
                <validHeaders>
                    <validHeader>/otherSupportedHeader.txt</validHeader>
                    <validHeader>http://www.company.com/yetAnotherSupportedHeader.txt</validHeader>
                </validHeaders>
                <quiet>false</quiet>
                <failIfMissing>true</failIfMissing>
                <aggregate>false</aggregate>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/**</include>
                    <include>**/test/**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>target/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>.clover/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                <mapping>
                    <jwc>XML_STYLE</jwc>
                    <application>XML_STYLE</application>
                    <myFileExtension>JAVADOC_STYLE</myFileExtension>
                </mapping>
                <useDefaultMapping>true</useDefaultMapping>
                <properties>
                    <year>${project.inceptionYear}</year>
                    <email>my@email.com</email>
                </properties>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <headerDefinitions>
                    <headerDefinition>def1.xml</headerDefinition>
                    <headerDefinition>def2.xml</headerDefinition>
                </headerDefinitions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i assume you are talking about the licenses of the dependencies.
For that purpose you can take a look at the [Maven License Verifier Plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.com/Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin/) which exactly checks such things. The best if you take a look at the [examples section](http://khmarbaise.github.com/Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin/example.html).